# Can i format dynamically created json into the required format for dev express charts

Tags: json, go, devexpress

I have written a go program for giving json as a response to the httpRequest,but i am able to create json in this format only :

```
{
  "Country": [
        "abc",
        "def",

    ],
    "Population": [
        "8388344",
        "343",

    ]
}
```

The content types are dynamically defined using map[string]string.Can someone please help me out to give the json in the below format:

```
[
    {
       "Country" :"abc",
       "Population" :"8388344"
    },
    {
        "Country" : "def",
        "Population" :"343"
    },
    ...
]
```

Please help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make a slice of structs. Adapted from the doc example:

```
type Tuple struct {
    Country    string
    Population string
}
tuples := []Tuple{
    {Country: "abc", Population: "1234"},
    {Country: "def", Population: "567"},
}

b, err := json.Marshal(tuples)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
os.Stdout.Write(b)
```

This produces:

```
[
    {"Country":"abc","Population":"1234"},
    {"Country":"def","Population":"567"}
]
```